# Find the integral of exponential

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, normed-spaces

For vectors $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ satisfying $\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert^2 = n\rho$ ($\mathbf{x}$ in a sphere with radius $\sqrt{n\rho}$), calculate

$$\int_\mathbf{x} \exp\left( -\left\Vert \mathbf{x} - V\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{a}\right\Vert^2 \right)d\mathbf{x}$$

where $V$ is a fixed $n\times n$ [unitary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) and $\mathbf{a}$ is a fixed $n\times 1$ vector.

I appreciate any hints. Thanks.

Comment: $\int_x$.  Is this supposed to be an n dimensional indefinite integral?

Comment: @herbsteinberg yes, it means integral over all $n$-dimensonial vectors $\mathbf{x}$

Comment: In the one dimensional case, it will be a variant of the error function.  Two dimensions might be handled by converting to polar coordinates.  I have never worked with higher dimensions.